# $x$ is a member of $X$ if it is a member of $Y$--what is proof that $X=Y$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$x$ is a member of $X$ if it is a member of $Y$. From this fact can we get to the statement $X=Y$?

Comment: That's just the definition of Y being a subset of X. You need X to also be a subset of Y for set equality.

Comment: To see this for yourself, try some examples and use a Venn diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t make this conclusion unless the converse is true as well that if y is a member of Y then it is also a member of X